# Making \floatrow figure go beyond text margin on each side

Tags: floatrow

I have a combined figure and table side by side which I'd like to be centered and go beyond text margin on each side by 3 cm. I can only make it pass the margin on the right side, the left side just follows along. Here's is my current take. Any suggestions?

```
\blindtext
\usepackage{floatrow}
% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
\hspace*{-3in}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[][]{\caption{subcaption1}}
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Files/attention.png}
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
  \label{sometjing}
}
\capbtabbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{lcc} \hline
  \textbf{Topic} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{CI LL 2.5\%} & \textbf{CI UL 97.5\%} \\ \hline
        1 & 0.0012 & -0.0433 & 0.0448 \\ 
        2 & -0.0357 & -0.0607 & -0.0112 \\ 
        3 & -0.0171 & -0.0607 & 0.0279 \\
        4 & -0.0245 & -0.0626 & 0.0187 \\ 
        5 & 0.0629 & 0.0047 & 0.1227 \\ 
        6 & 0.0499 & -0.044 & 0.1429 \\ 
        7 & 0.0595 & -0.0108 & 0.1261 \\
        8 & -0.1114 & -0.1784 & -0.042 \\ 
        9 & 0.0316 & -0.0693 & 0.1304 \\ 
        10 & 0.0348 & -0.0883 & 0.1515 \\
        11 & 0.0601 & 0.0066 & 0.1123 \\ 
        12 & -0.0014 & -0.101 & 0.0942 \\
  \end{tabular}
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
```

This is what it looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkoMU.jpg

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: you declare only three columns, but table has four ...

Comment: Floatrow uses a picture environment, so normal rules don't apply.  OTOH, there is nothing floatrow provides which cannot be done with subcaption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

With use of the `tabularray`, `booktabs`, `siunitx` packages (latter two loaded as `tabularray` libraries) and `caption` package for use of `captof{table}{...}` directive:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, 
                counter, varwidth}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} X[f]X[h] @{}},
             measure = vbox}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Files/attention.png} % <---
\caption{A figure}
\label{fig:something}   
    &   \begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} Q[c, si={table-format=2.0}]
                                       *{3}{X[c, m,  si={table-format=-1.4}]}
                                        @{}},
                              rowsep = 1pt,
                              row{1} = {guard, font=\small\bfseries}
                             }
                \toprule
            Topic   & Mean      & CI LL \qty{2.5}{\%}
                                            & CI UL \qty{97.5}{\%} \\
                \midrule
            1       & 0.0012    & -0.0433   &  0.0448 \\
            2       & -0.0357   & -0.0607   & -0.0112 \\
            3       & -0.0171   & -0.0607   &  0.0279 \\
            4       & -0.0245   & -0.0626   &  0.0187 \\
            5       & 0.0629    &  0.0047   &  0.1227 \\
            6       & 0.0499    & -0.044    &  0.1429 \\
            7       & 0.0595    & -0.0108   &  0.1261 \\
            8       & -0.1114   & -0.1784   & -0.042  \\
            9       & 0.0316    & -0.0693   &  0.1304 \\
            10      & 0.0348    & -0.0883   &  0.1515 \\
            11      & 0.0601    &  0.0066   &  0.1123 \\
            12      & -0.0014   & -0.101    &  0.0942 \\
                \bottomrule
                \end{tblr}
            \captionof{table}{A table}
            \label{tab:something}
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, image size is determined by `width` instead by `scale`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make it work. I've fiddled around with the code, but I still end up with this in the output. But thanks! https://imgur.com/a/83yUfsQ

Comment: @Quantizer, my suggestion, as it is in answer, works and gives showed result. Tested with `pdfLaTeX` and `LuaLatex` in recent MIKTeX as well in Overleaf. If you not get the same result as are showed in answer, than you change something in provided code or your sistem may be very outdated.